# Should we have a standard way of indicating deliberately malformed sentences?

Tags: discussion, style

For example, following common formatting I've seen in English style guides:

> He went to the shops

vs.

> Him went to the shops *

Or maybe italicizing bad sentences:

> *He went the shops*

Answer (score 13):

It's common practice in linguistic circles to mark a sentence ungrammatical with an asterisk, and of questionable grammaticality with a question mark.

- "He went to the shops."
- *"Him went to to the shops."
- ?"He goed to the shops." really contrived, but I hope you understand that I didn't have time to think of something better ;)

Anyway, I'm absolutely for this, and it should be part of the faq.

Comment: +1 for marking with an asterisk *before* the sentence

Comment: I have started using this convention: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/737/is-non-vegetarian-a-legal-word/749#749

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not very readable, we can strike out the sentence.

> <strike>Him went to the shops</strike>.