# Style guide for questions, answers, and comments

Tags: discussion, style

Style guides such as those on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style), [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers), [Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers) have been greatly helpful for me (and many in those communities) in creating well-written, well-formatted, easy-to-understand, easier-on-the-eye content. So, I would like to propose a style guide for this site.

Yes, I understand that style is more of a personal preference — this is perfectly all right for well written content.

This guide is meant to avoid poorly written, badly formatted, hard-to-understand, hideous looking content; we can all spot one, can't we? And to deal with one when we spot them.

This will be a good one-stop reference for everyone who is interested.

#### Note

This is a community wiki, so go ahead and edit this question and the answer(s) to best suit the purpose.

Answer (score 7):

I was just about to ask this question. Instead I will post an answer. :P

There seem to be a handful of styling targets on EL&U. These are the ones I could think of quickly:

- Should question titles be *questions*?
- Should we use single or double quotes around words in question titles?
- Should we use single or double quotes or italics or code markers around words in question bodies? ([Discussion 1](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363/what-emphasis-to-use-when-referring-to-words). [Discussion 2](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/how-would-we-like-to-format-our-keywords/3092#3092).)
- Should we use single or double quotes or italics or code markers around words in comments?
- Should we use `>` or backtick for example sentences? ([Discussion 1](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3358/should-we-fix-backticks). [Discussion 2](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3849/inline-quotes-formatting).)
- Should we include punctuation in question titles?
- Should we mark explicitly incorrect examples? ([See discussion](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/should-we-have-a-standard-way-of-indicating-deliberately-malformed-sentences).)
- Should we have a guideline regarding properly formatted links?
- Should *Word1 Vs Word2* be the standard format for such questions? ([See discussion](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/standard-format-for-questions-on-difference-between-two-specified-words).)

I provided relevant links where I knew about them. Please edit in more if you find them.

---

Another relevant question is whether people should edit with the intent of:

- Changing the style of the entire post
- Change the style of a post so it is consistent with itself
- Change the style of a post so it is consistent with the question

Comment: I feel like voting or answering each of those. Is that appropriate? How to do it though...in comments? in an answer? in separate answers?

Comment: @Mitch: If there isn't a dedicated discussion question for one already, just make one, post your thoughts, and then edit this answer with a link.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I handle some of these, from another answer.

> In this medium, where writing and typography has to express speech and sounds,
>   I use italics and boldface like this:
>
> - I use plain italics **only** for citing examples and titles. **Never** for emphasis.
> - I use boldface for emphasis. These are words that would be **LOUD** in my speech.
> - I use bold italics for technical terms, usually with capitals, and links if I have them.
> - I also use bold italics in examples to point out individual parts that get mentioned in the text.

In addition, I use single quotes only for glosses, and double quotes for actual quotations.

- Lushootseed /gʷidəq/ 'geoduck'
- "A man does not know what he is saying until he knows what he is not saying."  -- Chesterton

I also use bullets for examples, which I use a lot of; examples are **much** more useful than descriptions when discussing grammar, since nobody ever uses grammatical terms the same way.