# Path for adopting EL&U formatting standards

Tags: discussion, style

Aside from the relevant place to [track these discussions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/525/style-guide-for-questions-answers-and-comments), I believe we should decide the appropriate path for reaching a decision about a particular standard. Community run projects tend to get stuck debating; I want to avoid that.

Is there a solid SE path for adopting decisions that require input from the community? As in, something like this:

1. Acknowledge a problem
2. Propose solutions
3. Vote on solutions
4. Acknowledge a solution
5. Propose migrations to solution
6. Vote on migrations to solution
7. Choose migration path
8. Post a final summary somewhere people can find it

For something like a style guide, this could translate as such:

1. Acknowledge a target for the style guide (i.e. block quoting)
2. Propose solutions (i.e. `>` or codeblocks)
3. Vote on solutions
4. Acknowledge a solution
5. Propose migrations to solution (i.e. this style should be enforced; or this style is merely a suggestion; or edit only if other edits are necessary)
6. Vote on migrations to solution
7. Choose migration path
8. Post a final summary somewhere people can find it (i.e. update an "official" style guide and update all meta posts to point toward the resolution)

This is just a shot from the top of my head so please pick it apart. The goal here is to give us *some* way to bring resolution to some of these tough to resolve issues.

Comment: er.. what? isn't it better to just focus on the actual problems you wish to solve on this site, rather than creating a general methodology for solving any hypothetical problem?

Comment: @Jeff: You tell me. Any discussion on style just sits and collects dust while people edit titles and content in conflicting ways.

Comment: @mrhen can you provide some examples of the *specific* problems you want to solve, with hyperlinks?

Comment: @Jeff: The current topic involves [titles for questions on word differences](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/standard-format-for-questions-on-difference-between-two-specified-words). The [link](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/525/style-guide-for-questions-answers-and-comments) from this question has an answer with other formatting specific problems. Only three have open discussions; two of them have reached a reasonable conclusion but I highly doubt most realize it.

Comment: @Jeff: Ping. Was what I provided not what you were really asking for?

Comment: @mrhen I have no idea what this question is *about*

Comment: @Jeff: Okay. A short version: Requests and questions for style guides and suggestions just wither away here on meta but people continue to edit questions, titles, answers such that they line up with their personal preferences. This question was _trying_ to find a way to get everyone on the same page.

Comment: Why should they be on the same page? They aren't. The purported membership of this SE is not the actual membership, which disagrees on just about everything, because that's the way English Language Usage is discussed. It's hardly perfect, but lack of desire for organization is good evidence that we don't want to get organized that way. Despite the fact that people edit things in their own favorite ways, just like they talk.

Comment: I'd also add that this question has been answered here: [Style guide for questions, answers, and comments](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/525/)

Answer (score -1):

@MrHen, I believe that is what moderators are for. Besides having moderators make solving problems much much easier.

Comment: The moderators, as far as I know, have not posted anything on formatting standards.